# Encontrar semana del año con Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, date

Que tal amigos...tengo una inquietud...**¿Como podría lograr encontrar la semana del año a la cual pertenece una fecha especifica?** teniendo como referencia el día y el mes *Ejemplo:* a que semana del año pertenece el 4 de marzo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hace no mucho tuve que hacerlo también, llegué a este código:

1. Lo primero es crear una función, personalmente prefiero *crear* un método sobre el tipo de dato para poder usarlo de manera `cuatroDeMarzo.getWeekNumber()`, para hacerlo hay que acceder a `Date.prototype` y crear la función así:

   ```
   Date.prototype.getWeekNumber = function () {
       ...
   };
   ```
2. El código para la función es:

   ```
   Date.prototype.getWeekNumber = function () {
       var d = new Date(+this);  //Creamos un nuevo Date con la fecha de "this".
       d.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);   //Nos aseguramos de limpiar la hora.
       d.setDate(d.getDate() + 4 - (d.getDay() || 7)); // Recorremos los días para asegurarnos de estar "dentro de la semana"
       //Finalmente, calculamos redondeando y ajustando por la naturaleza de los números en JS:
       return Math.ceil((((d - new Date(d.getFullYear(), 0, 1)) / 8.64e7) + 1) / 7);
   };
   ```
3. El código lo podemos usar sobre cualquier objeto `Date`:

   ```
   new Date(2017, 2, 4).getWeekNumber(); // Resultado: 9
   ```

Comment: Tengo una duda: porque da como resultado 9, si la semana a la cual pertenece el 4 de abril es a la semana 13...? marzo es el mes 3...

Comment: lo mas extraño es que tanto con abril, como con marzo da semana 9

Comment: Recuerda el constructor de `Date`: **(año, mes[base 0], día)**. El 4 de marzo es `(2017, 2, 4)` como el primero de enero es `(2017, 0, 1)`; el 4 de abril sería `(2017, 3, 4)` y a mí me da como resultado `14`. ¡Espero que te sirva! ;)

Comment: aaa ok muchas gracias funciona perfectamente...no tuve en cuenta la base 0 al mes...

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo este código para que lo analices y lo estudies.

> Tomado de [cristalab](http://www.cristalab.com/tutoriales/como-obtener-el-numero-de-semana-del-ano-con-javascript-c74740l/) donde podrás entender más el funcionamiento lógico del código.

```js
function semanadelano($fecha){
    $const  =  [2,1,7,6,5,4,3]; 

    if ($fecha.match(/\//)){
        $fecha   =  $fecha.replace(/\//g,"-",$fecha);
    };

    $fecha  =  $fecha.split("-");

    $dia    =  eval($fecha[0]);
    $mes    =  eval($fecha[1]);
    $ano       =  eval($fecha[2]);   
    if ($mes!=0) {
        $mes--;
    };

    $dia_pri   =  new Date($ano,0,1); 
    $dia_pri   =  $dia_pri.getDay();
    $dia_pri   =  eval($const[$dia_pri]);
    $tiempo0   =  new Date($ano,0,$dia_pri);
    $dia       =  ($dia+$dia_pri);
    $tiempo1   =  new Date($ano,$mes,$dia);
    $lapso     =  ($tiempo1 - $tiempo0)
    $semanas   =  Math.floor($lapso/1000/60/60/24/7);

    if ($dia_pri == 1) {
        $semanas++;
    };

    if ($semanas == 0) {
        $semanas=52;
        $ano--;
    };

    if ($ano < 10) {
        $ano = '0'+$ano;
    };

    alert($semanas+" - "+$ano);
};

semanadelano('17/10/2017');
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos!

Comment: listo, muchas gracias

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow en español, te invito a que te hagas el [Tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y conozcas el funcionamiento de esta maravillosa comunidad